# Index out of bounds error for initialised array

Tags: arrays, kotlin

I have tried all array declarations. I have tried `Array<Int>` and `IntArray()`. I have initialised the array, and stored ascii values in it. I can access it in the first loop. But if I try to access it after that, it returns out of bounds error. If I use `array.first()` it says that the array is empty. I can iterate through the array but cannot access it. I do not know what the error is. I am new to Kotlin.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
fun main(args:Array<String>){
    var read=Scanner(System.`in`);
    var t=read.nextInt();
    while(t>=0){
        if(read.hasNextLine()){
            var s=read.nextLine();
            var e=0;
            var a=IntArray(s.length);
            for(i in s){
                a[e]=i.toInt();
                e++;
            }
            Arrays.sort(a);
            e=0;
            if(97==a[e]) System.out.println("-1");
            else{
                for(i in a) System.out.print(i.toChar());
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }
        t--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem isn't about the array, but rather about the scanner...

Comment: what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: what is the purpose of the first `read.nextInt()`? That call is probably the reason why it isn't working as you expect.... but I am still guessing...

Comment: just as a side-note: you consume the first int... and if there isn't anything after it (so basically you just write a number and enter a new line), then `s` is of length 0 and therefore `a[0]` can not be set...

Comment: There is a string given as input. I want to sort the string according to it's ASCII value. Moreover, I just want to know how to take input as an array. The input format is that there will be a number which will denote the number of strings that follow, each on a new line.

Comment: For example-                                                                                                               
2
dfsh
wtr

Comment: well... as long as you write "2 dfsh wtr" in one go, it will work... as you extract that int immediately and work with the rest of the string... well... "working" then still depends on what you expect if you only put in a single int, e.g. "1"... this will lead to the mentioned index-out-of-bounds... but why should that work? or what would you expect in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem isn't the array itself, but probably what you expected from the `Scanner`-calls. (Side-note that `Scanner` is `AutoClosable`, so you may want to use `use` with it, e.g. `Scanner(System.in).use { /* your code here */ }`.)

First of all, you are using `Scanner.nextInt()`. This means, that if you do not put a number first you will get an `InputMismatchException`.
So a number is a must. If you enter only a number, e.g. `1` you will then get your `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. The reason for it, is the following: the scanner basically reads `1\n` if you press enter after the number.
Now `nextInt()` extracts the number and `\n` remains. `Scanner.hasNextLine()` is therefore `true`, because it still has a line ending. `Scanner.nextLine()` then reads your input upto the first new line, which is basically now an empty string.

So maybe you already want to consume the first new line after the `nextInt()`, i.e. calling `read.nextLine()` immediately after `nextInt()` basically discarding everything that is following your number.

Due to your comment regarding what you actually want, namely "I just want to know how to take input as an array", I will now rather concentrate on that.

You can call `toCharArray()` on any `String`. That being said, the following is a simplified version of your code that reads a `String` from console and sorts it based on its integer representation:

```
readLine()!! // yes... we know that we enter something valuable here ;-)
       .toCharArray()
       .sortedBy(Char::toInt) // well... actually .sorted() should suffice as well
       .joinToString("")
```

That's it. That's all you need to get the character array from a `String` and to sort them by their integer representation. As `sortedBy` returns a `List` you need to join it again accordingly.

There are also other variants to accomplish what you want, but I think this is the simplest one.

If you still want to ask for a number beforehand, you can still do so:

```
print("How often? ")
val howOften = readLine()!!.toInt()
(1..howOften).forEach {
  print("${it + 1}. input: ")
  readLine()!!.toCharArray()
              .sorted()
              .joinToString("")
              .run(::println)
}
```

The same using a scanner would look as follows:

```
Scanner(System.`in`).use { scanner ->
  print("How often? ")
  val howOften =scanner.nextInt()
  scanner.nextLine()
  (1..howOften).forEach {
    print("${it + 1}. input: ")
    scanner.nextLine().toCharArray()
                      .sorted()
                      .joinToString("")
                      .run(::println)
  }
}
```

Comment: I would like to know about the `Scanner` error. Also, how can I store it in a variable, which I can later edit or access. If I need to impose a condition on the first element, for example.

Comment: This sort of code has worked before. If a number is declared, and multiple integers follow after it on a new line, with the same format. I do not understand how I can iterate through the array, and the program still returns that the array is empty.

Comment: @AditJain added an explanation for the scanner problem... let me know if it is clearer now... I didn't really understand your comment regarding "how can I store it in a variable, which I can later edit or access"... what did you mean by that? What do you want to store?

Comment: I got it. Thank you @Roland.